# How to integrate PayPal in Codeigniter Latest versions like 4.3.5

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, codeigniter-4

I want to integrate Paypal payment in Codeigniter 4.3.5.

For that I asked from chatgpt It suggest me to install **paypal/rest-api-sdk-php**. But when I run composer cmd to install sdk-php there was a message **Package paypal/rest-api-sdk-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.**
Then I studied the PayPal integration Guide but unfortunately could not find anything about php.

So, can any one tell me how can I integrate paypal in Codeigniter 4.3.5.
please suggest me the best way.?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no PayPal SDK for PHP, all are deprecated and should not be used.

All the official PayPal guides use node.js for their backend examples, as javascript is the most widely understood language. These routes shown in those samples can be implemented with any language, including PHP.

If you are searching for PHP-specific code examples, any you may find that use the deprecated paypal-php-sdk or checkout-php-sdk should no longer be used. Those SDKs are not supported.

Comment: Hi Preston PHX thanks for you response. Then what will be the best and secure solution. is It javascript.? and what If I redirect to paypal default page.? I want to implement/integrate a secure and best solution.

Comment: Your backend should create and capture the order using the PayPal API. This can be implemented with any environment. The examples given are for node.js. They are only examples.